# maven-compiler-plugin not found

Tags: java, maven, selenium, maven-compiler-plugin

I am learning Selenium and I would like to try add the maven-compiler-plugin to pom.xml and reimport maven settings. So I found this example to do it http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html and tried to add the code to the pom.xml. But the vrsion from the example 3.8.1 is red like on the screenshot. What it means? It is a copy from example.

[image]

Here is the whole pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>camaj.vladimir</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.tempus-fugit</groupId>
            <artifactId>tempus-fugit</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
            <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: you can go to Maven Central and look for that dependency, I see it at: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.8.1, so maybe you connected to a VPN ? or there is a repository configuration somewhere in your project ?, also will be more helpful if you post your entire pom.xml in a text snippet

Comment: I am on VPN. How is it related to loading plugins?

Comment: maybe there is a HOST name resolution error, I've been into problems because of that like not finding some sites, had to change for Google DNS (8.8.8.8)

Comment: Try cleaning/deleting your maven-compiler-plugin folder (and only that folder) in your local .m2

Comment: Added pom.xml ...

Comment: I just compiled it with mvn and is just working fine:
`[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @stackoverflow-maven-compiler-plugin-error`

Comment: After target in target folder it is ok. Thanks.

Comment: Please try to build your project on plain command line and safe the logging output ...that might help more.

Comment: @AlexAndrade That's not official maven Central Repository Database, that's a third party.

The official is https://search.maven.org
https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.8.1/maven-plugin

Answer (score 13):

In my case, I have changed the tags from plugin to dependency like it is in the [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.8.1).

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That's not official maven Central Repository Database, that's a third party.

The official is https://search.maven.org
https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.8.1/maven-plugin

Answer (score 9):

In my case the groupId for the plugin was missing:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.0</version>
...
```

Comment: i missed version. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin

Answer (score 8):

In my case, Spring Boot code works fine without changing anything, however, it gives the same error when I tried to commit in Git.

To solve this, I add the version info as follows and it worked.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

I've faced this issue with my old project (which was 100% working on my old ItelliJ IDEA) and newly installed ItelliJ IDEA:
in the pom.xml I had this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And IDEA throwed an error maven-compiler-plugin not found. I've added

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
```

and IDEA found the plugin, and after that I was free to remove  org.apache.maven.plugins without breaking IDEA

Answer (score 4):

I got this error with IntelliJ.  tried many ways, the below worked for me:

1. Close your IDE.
2. Delete "*.iml" and ".idea" -directories(present in the root folder of project)
3. Run "mvn clean install" from the command-line
4. Re-import your project into IDEA

Answer (score 3):

In IntelliJ you can right click on 3.8.1 scroll down to Maven and select "Reimport". This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, invalidating cache and restarting solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I went to

```
.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-compiler-plugin
```

and removed older version. It worked

Answer (score 1):

Add the Following code in your pom the issue will resolve

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
            <configuration>
                <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                <useFile>false</useFile>
                <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <forkMode>once</forkMode>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testing.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

Make sure you are reimporting your dependency after adding plugins

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your project so that the dependencies are updated from Maven side.

To update:

1. Change the file structure to project view.
2. Right click on project name -> Maven -> Reload project

And it will download all the necessary dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be due to `proxy` setup on your system in Maven settings.

You can remove/backup the previous maven `settings.xml` file and this should work.

```bash
mv ~/.m2/settings.xml ~/.m2/settings.xml.bak
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I was also facing this suddenly, I just did maven clean install. It worked for me!!!